# cleared sketch still on canvas in ipad browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, canvas

I just get confused about canvas clear stuff -- the sketch has been cleared from canvas, but when I click the canvas to draw something new, the cleared sketch just come back at the same position again. It looks like the sketch has been saved to some "cookies", which has been reloaded when the next time clicking the canvas or mouse over the canvas. This situation only happen in ipad browser. Below is my code TQ.

```
$('.reset-img').click(function(){

                    $('#tools_sketch').sketch().actions = [];  
                    var myCanvas = document.getElementById("tools_sketch");
                    var ctx2 = myCanvas.getContext('2d');

                    ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);
                });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738717/javascript-canvas-clear-redraw/30741672#30741672

Comment: i had try it, still can't work, the cleared sketch still on

Comment: We'd need to see more code in that case as the problem is very likely not in the shown part.

Answer (score 0):

i had solved my problem.Just add 
$('#tools_sketch').sketch().actions = null; 
before 
$('#tools_sketch').sketch().actions = [];

Thank for you all's concern.