# How to make the effect of moving the image in the window canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

For example I have a limited canvas, smaller width/height than the uploaded image in it.
Guys how to make the effect of moving the image in the canvas window? In other words, the canvas window does not change, and the picture we "run". thanks

[image]

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You can choose the height and width of an image on the canvas so it would fit. If you want to move an image just change the `x` and `y` location of where it's drawn. For example, if you increment `x` positively that would move the image left

Comment: something like this? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/EXwWyx

Comment: @MichaelCoker  no, I need to capture the current position coordinates and moving around the image. This is only part of the overall image

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek thanks, good suggest. can you show an example of your proposal?

Comment: You'll need more than one image to make a "run" sequence. https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/animation-for-beginners-how-to-animate-a-character-running--cms-25730

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30739547/3200577

Basically, the way that html canvas works is very different from how html elements are rendered and painted. Whereas you can select and move an html element on the page, you cannot select and move something that you have added to a canvas because *all you can do on a canvas is add and clear pixels*. So, when you add an image to a canvas, you are adding the pixels of the image to the canvas. If you were to add the image again but a little to the left, then it would look like you've added two images, where the second one overlaps the first, which is not what you want.

So, to animate the motion of an image on the canvas, you need to:

- choose an x and y as the position of the image on the canvas
- draw the image on the canvas at x and y
- increment the values of x and y to the new position that you want
- clear the canvas
- redraw the image at the new x and y

A more abstract description of this flow: basically, you need to create, store, and manage your own *model* of what your canvas looks like; when you want to add, remove of change things that you've painted on the canvas, you actually aren't going to be adding, removing, or changing anything *directly* on the canvas. You would add, remove and change things in your own model, clear the canvas, and then redraw the canvas on the basis of your model.

For instance, your model might be a JS object such as

```
myModel = {
    images: [
        { url: "my/picture.png", position: [123,556] },
        { url: "another/picture.jpg", position: [95,111] }
    ]
}
```

and you would write functions for 1) incrementing the values of the positions of the images in the model, 2) clearing the canvas, and 3) drawing your model onto the canvas. Then, you would create a loop (using `requestAnimationFrame` or `setInterval`) that would repeatedly execute those three functions.

For large or complex projects, I strongly recommend using a canvas library such as paperjs, which implements that flow for you (so that you don't have to think about creating a model and clearing and redrawing the canvas). It provides high-level functionality such as animation right out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

### Animation basic movement

Like all animation to make something appear as if it moves is to draw a sequence of still images (a frame), each image slightly different. If the rate of frames are high enough (over about 20 per second) the human eye and mind see the sequence of still images as a continuous movement. From the first movies to today's high end games this is how animation is done.

So for the canvas the process of drawing a frame is simple. Create a function that clears the canvas, draws what you need, exit the function so that the browser can move the completed frame to the display. (Note that while in the function anything draw on the canvas is not seen on the display, you must exit the function to see what is drawn)

To animate you must do the above at at least more than 20 times a seconds. For the best results you should do it at the same rate as the display hardware shows frames. For the browser that is always 60 frames per second (fps).

#### Animation in the browser

To help sync with the display you use the function `requestAnimationFrame(myDrawFunction)` it tells the browser that you are animating, and that the results of the rendering should be displayed only when the display hardware is ready to show a new complete frame, not when the draw function has exited (which may be halfway through a hardware frame).

#### Animation Object

So as a simple example let's create a animation object.

```
const imageSrc = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7qq2.png?s=328&g=1";
const myImage = {
  posX: 0, // current position of object
  posY: 0,
  speed: 3, // speed in pixels per frame (1/60th second)
  direction: 0, // direction of movement in radians 0 is at 3oclock
  image: (() => { // create and load an image (Image will take time to load
    // and may not be ready until after the code has run.
    const image = new Image;
    image.src = imageSrc;
  })(),
```

#### Draw function

Then a draw function that draws the object on the canvas

```
  draw(ctx) {
    ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.posX, this.posY);
  },
```

#### Update function

As we are animating we need to move the object once per frame, to do this we create a update function.

```
  update() {
    this.posX += (mx = Math.cos(this.direction)) * this.speed;
    this.posY += (my = Math.sin(this.direction)) * this.speed;
  }
} // end of object
```

#### Many times a second

To do the animation we create a main loop that is call for every hardware display frame via `requestAnimationFrame`.

```
function mainLoop() {
  // clear the canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  // update the obj
  myImage.update();
  // draw the object
  myImage.draw(ctx);
  // request the next frame
  requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
  // note all of the above code is not seen by the use until the
  // next hardwares display frame. If you used setTimeout or setInterval
  // then it would be displayed when this function exits (which may be 
  // halfway through a frame resulting in the animation being cut in two)
}
// request the first frame
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
```

### Some extras

And that is the most basic animation. of course you need to get the canvas context and wait for the image to load. Also because the image moves of the canvas you would need to check when it does and either stop the animation.

Eg to stop animation is image is off screen

```
if(myImage.posX < canvas.width){  // only render while image is on the canvas
   requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
} else {
   console.log("Animation has ended");
}
```

Now to put it together as a demo.

---

### The demo

The demo has some extra smarts to make the image wrap around, ensure that the image has loaded before starting and make it start off screen, but is basicly the same as outlined above.

```js
// get the 2D context from the canvas id
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
// setup the font and text rendering
ctx.font = "32px arial";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

// create the image object and load the image
const imageSrc = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7qq2.png?s=328&g=1";
const myImage = {
  posX: 0, // current position of object
  posY: 0,
  speed: 3, // speed in pixels per frame (1/60th second)
  direction: 0, // direction of movement in radians 0 is at 3oclock
  image: (() => { // create and load an image (Image will take time to load
    // and may not be ready until after the code has run.
    const image = new Image;
    image.src = imageSrc;
    // to start move the image of the display
    image.onload = function(){
      const imageDiagonalSize = Math.sqrt(
        image.width * image.width + image.height * image.height
      )
      myImage.posX = (canvas.width / 2) - imageDiagonalSize - Math.cos(myImage.direction) * imageDiagonalSize;
      myImage.posX = (canvas.height / 2) - imageDiagonalSize - Math.sin(myImage.direction) * imageDiagonalSize;
    }
    return image;
  })(),
  draw(ctx) {
    ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.posX, this.posY);
  },
  update() {
    var mx,my; // get movement x and y
    this.posX += (mx = Math.cos(this.direction)) * this.speed;
    this.posY += (my = Math.sin(this.direction)) * this.speed;
    // if the image moves of the screen move it to the other side
    if(mx > 0) { // if moving right
      if(this.posX > canvas.width){
         this.posX = 0-this.image.width;
      }
    }else if(mx < 0) { // if moving left
      if(this.posX + this.image.width < 0){
         this.posX = canvas.width;
      }
    }
    if(my > 0) { // if moving down
      if(this.posY > canvas.height){
         this.posY = 0-this.image.height;
      }
    }else if(my < 0) { // if moving up
      if(this.posY + this.image.height < 0){
         this.posY = canvas.height;
      }
    }      
  }
}

function mainLoop() {
  // clear the canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  if(myImage.image.complete) { // wait for image to load
    myImage.update();
    myImage.draw(ctx);
  }else{ // some feedback to say the image is loading
    ctx.fillText("Loading image..",canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
  }
  // request the next frame
  requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
// request the first frame
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!-- id's must be unique to the page -->
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

- Please note that the above code uses ES6 and will need a code pre processor like Babel to run on legacy browsers.