# When setting a transparent background to Canvas, the animation starts to leave traces

Tags: javascript, canvas

Animation works great when I set any color to the background. But when I put a transparent background, the animated “waves” begin to leave traces. How can I fix this?

https://codepen.io/obiwan-kenobi/pen/JebWjG

```
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,0)'; 
ctx.fillRect.apply(ctx, _toConsumableArray(bounds.params));
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRTdn.png)

Comment: Use `clearRect` instead of `fillRect` at line 338. And you don't need to set `ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,0)"; `

Comment: @enxaneta, Thank you! Yes! This is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

It leaves traces because you need to redraw the changed areas of your canvas, or simpler, redraw the entire scene.

You are using a pencil and are drawing every frame on the same sheet of paper without using your eraser. Thats is why. :)

Comment: I understand this, I thought about it, but I do not understand Canvas. Which team can clean the scene?

Comment: You must redraw your scene entirely : check https://stackoverflow.com/a/30739547/3679206