# Trouble decrementing fill rectangle for health bars in javascript using setInterval, works with incrementing

Tags: javascript, setinterval, addeventlistener, fill, buttonclick

I am trying to build a mini web game like tamagotchi however I am having trouble with the health bar status of the script. For instance when I have `setInterval` set to decrement the cleanliness, hunger and happiness bar I can see the change through `console.log` but the bar does not decrease when I'm looking at the `html`. However, it works just fine when I have the setInterval function or even the button click event listener to increment. Neither work when I'm trying to set the status to go down. I'm not sure why it's happening but I'm still actively looking for answers.

```
window.onload = function() {
  document
    .getElementById("clean-button")
    .addEventListener("click", clickedCleanButton);
  document
    .getElementById("feed-button")
    .addEventListener("click", clickedFeedButton);
  document
    .getElementById("play-button")
    .addEventListener("click", clickedPlayButton);

  let sprite_info = {
    name: "giratina",
    happiness: 800,
    hunger: 800,
    cleaniness: 800,
    age: 0
  };

  //hunger bar function, will decrease every 10000ms
  /* work on decreasing bars per 10,000ms*/
  setInterval(function() {
    UpdateSpriteInfo();
    sprite_info["cleaniness"] -= 50;
    //sprite_info['hunger'] -= 50;
    //sprite_info['happiness'] -= 50;
    console.log(sprite_info["cleaniness"]);
  }, 10000);

  function clickedCleanButton() {
    sprite_info["cleaniness"] += 50;
    console.log(sprite_info["cleaniness"]);
    UpdateSpriteInfo();
  }

  function clickedFeedButton() {
    sprite_info["hunger"] += 50;
    console.log(sprite_info["hunger"]);
    UpdateSpriteInfo();
  }

  function clickedPlayButton() {
    sprite_info["happiness"] += 50;
    console.log(sprite_info["happiness"]);
    UpdateSpriteInfo();
  }

  function UpdateSpriteInfo() {
    //health display that grows by 50 with button click
    canvas_health = document.getElementById("health_display");
    health_bar = canvas_health.getContext("2d");
    health_bar.fillStyle = "green";
    health_bar.fillRect(0, 0, sprite_info["cleaniness"], 50);

    //hunger display
    canvas_hunger = document.getElementById("hunger_display");
    hunger_bar = canvas_hunger.getContext("2d");
    hunger_bar.fillStyle = "lightblue";
    hunger_bar.fillRect(0, 0, sprite_info["hunger"], 50);

    //happiness display
    canvas_happiness = document.getElementById("happiness_display");
    happiness_bar = canvas_happiness.getContext("2d");
    happiness_bar.fillStyle = "pink";
    happiness_bar.fillRect(0, 0, sprite_info["happiness"], 50);
  }
};
```

Comment: You  need to clear the canvas before drawing [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30741672/681929)

Comment: nitpick, but `sprite_info` should be a const. remember, any non primitive const in js are mutable, they just can't be reassigned.

Comment: Thank you for the comments I have things working now!